# Entropies of Solvation for Chlorate and Nitrate Anions

Tags: solutions, entropy

Can anyone find any data on the entropies of solvation for these two anions in water solution? I can't find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [graph on p. 65](http://books.google.com/books?id=JoNUVLrNg14C&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=Entropies%20of%20Solvation%20for%20Chlorate%20and%20Nitrate%20Anions&source=bl&ots=hHBaWdVYeh&sig=2OXVRCGEe351WJNwleMRPg5jdh4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tCG0U66-CdCkyASyoYDAAQ&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=Entropies%20of%20Solvation%20for%20Chlorate%20and%20Nitrate%20Anions&f=false), it puts the entropy of solvation (298 K) for chlorate and nitrate at about 25 and 21 kJ/mol respectively.  [This reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=frE5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA118&lpg=PA118&dq=Entropies%20of%20Solvation%20for%20Chlorate%20and%20Nitrate%20Anions&source=bl&ots=3qXhfKQPhg&sig=aWWbaQ2hiUyjiMEgMbHKp_CYqQM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tCG0U66-CdCkyASyoYDAAQ&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Entropies%20of%20Solvation%20for%20Chlorate%20and%20Nitrate%20Anions&f=false) suggests that the entropy term for nitrate is 116 J/(K-mol), multiplying that by 298 K yields 34.6 kJ/mol.

Comment: Would you say that the difference between 25 and 21 kJ/mol is a big difference?

Comment: No, as a rule of thumb 5.5 kJ/mol (1.4 kcal/mol) shifts an equilibrium by a factor of 10.  So if two molecules A and B were in equilibrium and the free energy difference between the two favored A by 5.5 kJ/mol, then you have an [A]/[B] equilibrium of about 91/9, relatively speaking, a small difference.  The difference your looking at is even less than this.

Comment: Should have pointed out that the above comment is a "room temperature" statement.  While I'm at it, let me add another point of comparison to demonstrate that 4 kJ/mol is a small difference: the height of the rotational barrier in ethane is around 12 kJ/mol.

Comment: @Dissenter  Just looking for feedback - what would have constituted an answer that you could have "accepted"?

Comment: I don't think your answer is inadequate; I was just holding out for more opinions.